# How to fix FPS oscilating issue, with QThread and multiple cams OpenCV

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, qt-creator, qthread

I'm Making a OpenCV code with QT to record 2 cameras simultaneously, i run 2 instances of the same Multithread Class, i check the FPS manually, framesCaptured/secondsWriting, idk if there is a data race, i don't think so because  i declare each variable inside the function.

The problem: when checking the fps manually(cv::CAP_PROP_FPS doesn't work well), im getting slightly wrong values like 5 fps more or less, that cause dyssynchrony, fps_cam1 = 23; fps_cam2 = 28; when im get these values the cams desynchronize, the best im getting is both cams 28 fps, look at the:

multithread.h:

```
#ifndef MULTITHREAD_H
#define MULTITHREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QString>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <QDir>
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <atomic>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMutex>
#include <time.h>
#include <QWaitCondition>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
class MultiThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MultiThread(std::string winName, int cam, std::atomic<bool> *checked, std::atomic<int> *waitSync, QMutex *gMutex);
    ~MultiThread();


    void run() override
    {
       record_cam();

    }

    void record_cam();

    void configureCaption(std::string fileName, int fourcc);


    void setFileName(QDir filename);
    void setCam(int camera);

private:

    QDir m_filename; //Filename .avi
    std::string m_winName;//Opencv window name
    int m_cam; //Cam to record

    QMutex mutex;
    QMutex *globalMutex;
    QWaitCondition waitSync;


    std::atomic_bool *m_recordChecked; //Pause stop variable
    std::atomic<int> *m_waitSync; // Sync variable


    //bool m_setCamerastoRecord;

//    cv::VideoCapture *videoCam;
//    cv::VideoWriter *video;

    //Frame
    cv::Mat frame; //Frame of video

    int m_fps;
    double seconds;

private slots:

signals:
    void sendFrame(std::string winName, const cv::Mat frame);

};

#endif // MULTITHREAD_H
```

multithread.cpp code:

```
#include "multithread.h"

MultiThread::MultiThread(std::string winName, int cam, std::atomic<bool> *checked, std::atomic<int> *waitSync, QMutex *gMutex) :
    m_winName(winName), m_cam(cam), m_recordChecked(checked), m_waitSync(waitSync), globalMutex(gMutex)
{
}

void MultiThread::record_cam()
{
    QString videoFilename = m_filename.absolutePath();
    int fourcc = cv::VideoWriter::fourcc('M','J','P','G'); //Set forcc variable

    if(m_cam == -1)
        return;

#if (defined (LINUX) || defined (__linux__) )
    cv::VideoCapture videoCam(m_cam, cv::CAP_V4L2);
#elif (defined (_WIN32) || defined (_WIN64))
    cv::VideoCapture videoCam(m_cam, cv::CAP_DSHOW);
#endif

    if(!videoCam.isOpened()){
        std::cerr<<"Cannot open VideoCapture cam " + std::to_string(m_cam);
        return;
    }

    int width = 0;//cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH;
    int height = 0;//cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT;

    if(m_winName =="Principal")//800x600 in future
    {
        width = 640;
        height = 480;
    }
    else if(m_winName =="Auxiliar")
    {
        width = 640;
        height = 480;
    }

    videoCam.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,width);
    videoCam.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,height);

        cv::Mat frameCopy = frame.clone();
        int frames_number = 200;
        time_t start,end;

        time(&start);

        for(int i=0;i<frames_number;i++)
        {
            videoCam.read(frameCopy);
        }

        time(&end);

        double seconds = difftime(end, start);
        int fps = (frames_number/ seconds);

    std::cerr<<m_winName+":"<<fps<<std::endl;

    cv::VideoWriter video;

    video.open(videoFilename.toStdString(), fourcc, fps, frameCopy.size(), true);

    if(!video.isOpened())
    {
        std::cerr<<"Cannot open VideoWriter video";
        return;
    }

    (*m_waitSync)++;

    while(*m_waitSync != 2)
        ;

    std::cerr<<m_winName + " Entering thread"<<std::endl;

    while(videoCam.read(frameCopy) && m_recordChecked->load()==true)
    {
        video.write(frameCopy);
        //Send cv::MAT frame to MainWindow, so i cam cv::imshow without bugs(doesn't work in QThread)
        emit sendFrame(m_winName, frameCopy); 
    }

    video.release();
    videoCam.release();
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void MultiThread::setCam(int camera)
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);//Data race
    if(m_cam != camera)
       m_cam = camera;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void MultiThread::setFileName(QDir filename)
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);//Data race
    m_filename = filename;
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
MultiThread::~MultiThread()
{
}
```

I tried cv::CAP_PROP_FPS flag, increase frame count to get more precision with fps, generating the videowriter with fps=1, and later call another function that recreate the video with correct fps(i think this could work, but im not getting results)

```
void MultiThread::configureCaption(std::string fileName, int fourcc)
{
    cv::VideoCapture newVideo(fileName);
    int frames = newVideo.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);
    int fps = frames/seconds;

    cv::VideoWriter video(fileName, fourcc, fps, frame.size(),true);

    for(int i = 0; i<frames; i++)
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(15));
        newVideo.read(frame);
        video.write(frame);
    }
}
```